# how to make new live / cloned element resizable with jquery ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

i am creating html elements live and appending them to the window.

The issue im having is that i can't use jquery ui on them. I have tried the deffer method, but that doesn't work as well.

What i am trying to accomplish is to clone the last `div`, add it to the `container` and make it `resizable`

here's some code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/945p6/):

```
<div id="container" class="ui-widget-content">
     <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Containment</h3>

    <div id="" class="ui-state-active resizable">
         <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>

    </div>
    <div id="" class="ui-state-active resizable">
         <h3 class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>

    </div>
</div>
<button class="add">add</button>

#container {width: 600px;height: 300px;}
#container h3 {text-align: center;margin: 0;margin-bottom: 10px;}
.resizable {width: 100px;height: 100px;float: left;}
.resizable, #container {padding: 0.5em;}

var dfd = $.Deferred();
dfd.done(function () {
    var lastDiv = $('.resizable').last();
    var lastDivClone = lastDiv.clone();
    lastDivClone.appendTo('#container');
    return lastDivClone;
});

$('.add').on("click", function () {
    var x = dfd.resolve();
    x.resizable("enable");
});

$(".resizable").resizable({
    containment: "#container",
    grid: 50
});
```

any ideas?

Comment: Put this in done and see what happens :)

$(lastDivClone).resizable({
  containment: "#container",
  grid:50
})
Essentially, the element isn't in the DOM when you call the resizable method so you need to call resizable on the element you're appending

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the resizable handle first.

```
lastDivClone.appendTo('#container').find('.ui-resizable-handle').remove()
    .end().resizable({
        containment: "#container",
        grid: 50
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/945p6/2/

Comment: @Omar very off topic ... why?

Comment: I need help there, interesting mystery =)